# Unable to display images from local inventory in Play 2 framework using Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have few images stored in local directory.
The path of the images are stored in a local database.

I am unable to display the images in front end.

Model code :

```
package models

case class Post(image_path: String)
```

.HTML code :

```
@for(post <- posts) {

<img src='@routes.Assets.versioned("@post.body")'
                        class="img-fluid">

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `@post.image_path` in the HTML template?